# Can any users change locale language?

Tags: localization

So, I have translated my theme with the Loco Translate plugin, and now I need give opportunity for unauthorized users to choose the language which they want to use. I see that WordPress uses .mo files which language index coincide with locale language.

If the language of my site is ru_Ru, then WP will use ru_Ru.mo, right? How I can implement opportunity of choice for users?

P.S. I know about WPML plugin,and about multisite too. =) I'm just trying to solve this task.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to work on any .mo files for allowing your users to switch between language. Loco translate plugin comes with this features.

So what you need to do is to follow the steps below :-

1. Navigate to Loco Translate menu
2. Find and select plugin / theme you want to translate
3. Create template file
4. Choose and create language file, which you want your users to choose from
5. Add translations for that particular language

And you are all good for multilanguage setup....